# Unexpected white blinks

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, android-appcompat

When we simply start any new activity via "startActivity", we have strange behavoiur, we see short-time unexpected white blink. The issue is related to Android Version 6.0.1 and Above, and only happens, if you call "startActivity". Workaround is quite simple, we have to call always "startActivityForResult".
But the origin of the issues still unclear, before we did not have such issues.

Thanks in advance.